# Python pandas, converting multiple columns of strings into time?

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, scikit-learn

I have a pandas DataFrame which consists of many columns which are strings represented as times (e.g. "8:14:30.123"). Is there an efficient way of converting all of these columns into numerical values? I did some research and found panda `to_datetime()` function, but it works only for one column at a time, and I have too many columns to iterate over.

Comment: Putting out a sample of the input would help people to answer your question immensely.

Comment: "Too many columns to iterate over"? Please define "too many." 100s? 1,000s? Still not too many. While some functions work well on entire DataFrames, others are more commonly applied to Series / columns. They're still vectorized / aggregate operations. Unlike iterating over every data cell, iterating over a series of columns performing column operations isn't particularly inefficient.

Comment: Ah I should've elaborated earlier. I have 100 time columns of 750k elements each. Calling `to_datetime` on one column takes 2 minutes, and I don't know how long it takes to complete all of them.

Comment: You could use applymap() and pass it to_datetime.

Answer (score 2):

You could iterate through them and apply the `to_datetime` function OR

when you are reading it as CSV, use the `parse_dates` argument:

> parse_dates : boolean, list of ints or names, list of lists, or dict
>   If True -> try parsing the index. If [1, 2, 3] -> try parsing columns
>   1, 2, 3 each as a separate date column. If [[1, 3]] -> combine columns
>   1 and 3 and parse as a single date column. {‘foo’ : [1, 3]} -> parse
>   columns 1, 3 as date and call result ‘foo’ A fast-path exists for
>   iso8601-formatted dates.

#### Update:

If its speed you want, you would be better off using the below function to convert columns to datetime.

```
def lookup(s):
    """
    This is an extremely fast approach to datetime parsing.
    For large data, the same dates are often repeated. Rather than
    re-parse these, we store all unique dates, parse them, and
    use a lookup to convert all dates.
    """
    dates = {date:pd.to_datetime(date) for date in s.unique()}
    return s.apply(lambda v: dates[v])
```

The advantage is that duplicate dates would be lookedup instead of being converted to datetime again and again. There seems to be a significant speed difference:

```
$ python date-parse.py
to_datetime: 5799 ms
dateutil:    5162 ms
strptime:    1651 ms
manual:       242 ms
lookup:        32 ms
```

Source: https://github.com/sanand0/benchmarks/tree/master/date-parse